What are the options to migrate VSS 6.0 to Azure DevOps if you do not have VSS 2005?
from numerous links on SF and research, I have learned that to successfully migrate from VSS 6.0 to Azure DevOps(or to TFS for that matter), that VSS has to be upgraded to VSS 2005.  The issue I am having is that I cannot find a viable copy of VSS 2005 to upgrade too.
Things I have tried:
Numerous Internet searches and Searching all over Microsoft.
I was wondering if anyone had any experience with this, and how they accomplished the migration.

Does anyone know where can I get a copy of VSS 2005?
What are some other options to migrate VSS 6.0 to Azure DevOps?
What are some other repositories that would allow you migrate VSS 6.0 to it?

Any and all suggestions, recommendations, references, guidance appreciated.
Thanks.

As far as I know, Visual SourceSafe 2005 was end of support(Mainstream End Date: Jul 10, 2012. Extended End Date: Jul 11, 2017). We can no longer download it from the Microsoft site. Refer to this announcement: Microsoft Visual SourceSafe 2005

Does anyone know where can I get a copy of VSS 2005?

I found the en_vss_2005.iso in this site: Files for msdn_2023. You can navigate to the site and search: en_vss_2005.iso . Then you can install the vss2005 based on the iso file.
To  migrate your VSS to Azure DevOps Service, you can use Visual Source Safe Upgrade Tool for Team Foundation Server.
For more detailed steps, you can refer to this blog: Visual Source Safe (VSS) to TFS Migration
In step two of the Upgrade Wizard, you can directly connect to your Azure DevOps Service Organization and pick a team project as target destination. In this case, you can migrate VSS to Azure DevOps Service.
